# Next Js 13+, page not re-rendering on server

Tags: next.js, next-auth

In Next.js 13+, the app directory, I am trying to validate a user before they can access a page. I want to have a reusable function that I can pass the page into as in the code below.

The issue is that if I click on the link that directs me to the page below, I get the initial render, but consecutive clicks do not rerender the page. In other words, `console.log(session)` is not being called anymore; it is only called on the initial click. However, if I include the content of `validateSignInOrRedirect` into the page, it works fine, and `console.log(session)` prints on every click.

This doesn't call console.log(session) on every click:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {  getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { PageProps } from '@/.next/types/app/layout';

async function  page() {
    return (
        <div>
            You are allowed to view this page
        </div>
    );
}

export default await validateSigInOrRedirect(page);

async function validateSigInOrRedirect(page: any): Promise<React.ComponentType<PageProps>> {

    const session = await getServerSession();
    console.log(session);

    if (!session || !session.user?.email) {
        return () => redirect("/auth/signin")
    }

    return (originalProps) => page({ ...originalProps, user: session?.user });

}
```

This calls console.log(session) on every click:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {  getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

async function  page() {
    const session = await getServerSession();
    console.log(session);

    if (!session || !session.user?.email) {
        return () => redirect("/auth/signin")
    }

    return (
        <div>
            You are allowed to view this page
        </div>
    );
}

export default await page;
```

I want to wrap the page like this: `export default await validateSigInOrRedirect(page);`

This isn't just about authentication, the example above is just a simple use case. I have other logic that I would like to reuse before accessing a certain type of page, example:  `export default await processSomething(page);`

Comment: Try using [middleware](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware) instead.

Comment: @Minn Thank you, but I would like to implement it as above and understand what the issue is